# direction routes - only the main streets

Tags: google-maps-api-3

this is my example http://gidzior.net/map/v3_animate_marker_directions.html (i'm using placeholder in the input), thx for the GM code to geocodezip.com here

in my example i'm using Google Maps API 3, is it possible set only main streets in the direction routes ?

```
    var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;
  var markerArray = [];
  var position;
  var marker = null;
  var polyline = null;
  var poly2 = null;
  var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;
  var zoomed;

    var myPano;   
    var panoClient;
    var nextPanoId;
  var timerHandle = null;

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        //marker.myname = label;
        // gmarkers.push(marker);

    /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });*/
    return marker;
}


function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    // Create a map and center it on Warszawa.
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    address = 'warszawa'
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    });

    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
  }



    var steps = []

    function calcRoute(){

if (timerHandle) { clearTimeout(timerHandle); }
if (marker) { marker.setMap(null);}
polyline.setMap(null);
poly2.setMap(null);
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map
    }
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
        var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: travelMode
        };

        // Route the directions and pass the response to a
        // function to create markers for each step.
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var route = response.routes[0];
        startLocation = new Object();
        endLocation = new Object();

        // For each route, display summary information.
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
          if (i == 0) { 
            startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
            startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
            // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
            marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
          }
          endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
          endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
              polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
              bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);



            }
          }
        }

        polyline.setMap(map);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
//        createMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red");
    map.setZoom(18);
    startAnimation();
    zoomed=false;
    }                                                    
 });
}



      var step = 50; // 5; // metres
      var tick = 100; // milliseconds
      var eol;
      var k=0;
      var stepnum=0;
      var speed = "";
      var lastVertex = 1;


//=============== animation functions ======================
      function updatePoly(d) {
        // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
        if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

        if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
           if (poly2.getPath().getLength()>1) {
             poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength()-1)
           }
           poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
        } else {
          poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),endLocation.latlng);
        }
      }


      function animate(d) {
// alert("animate("+d+")");
        if (d>eol) {
          map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
          marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
          return;
        }
        if (d>eol-1000 && zoomed!=true) {
          map.setZoom(15); // or whatever value
          zoomed=true;
        }
        var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
        map.panTo(p);
        marker.setPosition(p);
        updatePoly(d);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
      }


function startAnimation() {
        eol=polyline.Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
        // map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(polyline.getAt(0),G_START_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(new GMarker(polyline.getVertex(polyline.getVertexCount()-1),G_END_ICON));
        // marker = new google.maps.Marker({location:polyline.getPath().getAt(0)} /* ,{icon:car} */);
        // map.addOverlay(marker);
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#0000FF", strokeWeight:10});
        // map.addOverlay(poly2);
        setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have options `avoidHighways` and `avoidTolls`, but there's nothing like `avoidByways`. This is because the service needs to get as close as possible to `origin` and `destination` and it may only be possible to use byways to get there. `avoidHighways` is possible because it's highly likely there is *some* route from A to B without using a motorway. [An exception is where a motorway connects two islands and there is no minor road route: I don't know if `avoidHighways` merely *avoids* them and the API would in fact use a highway if there is no alternative.]

The API will favour fast routes, so main streets will be preferred by default. If you were able to instruct the API to use *only* main streets, it is entirely possible that it would not be able to find directions between A and B.

Comment: This is a great pity because my final location is very close to the main road and it would be very useful for me, especially now that the route often passes through a closed road

maybe I can put a point on the road which must lead by each route i mean every direction path must lead by some point

Comment: I nearly mentioned waypoints in my answer. If they may be useful to direct a route near to the destination, give them a go. Unfortunately there is no `avoidPoints` either (for example, to avoid a temporarily closed street), although that was requested years ago.

Comment: works perfect, i have one more question can i hide icon of the waypoint

Comment: You can use `suppressMarkers:true` but then you would need to explicitly add markers A and B back on the map. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions

Comment: once again THX for your great help